# QTableView обработка выделения строк

Tags: c++, qt4

Совсем запутался с обработкой выделения строк в QTableView...
соединяю сигнал изменения текущего item'a:

`connect(ui.table->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(onRowChange(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)), Qt::QueuedConnection);`

в слоте получаю кол-во выделенных строк так:

```
int cntSelRow = ui.table->selectionModel()->selectedRows().size()
```

В итоге если допустим в таблице 5 строк, я выделяю вместе 2,3,4 строки ( `cntSelRow = 3` ), а затем выделяю одну 5ю строку, то `cntSelRow = 1`, НО! Если я выделю не 5ю строку а допустим 3ю, то  `cntSelRow = 3`, почему так? Почему selectionModel()->selectedRows не успевает изменится?

Comment: Возможно вам надо выствить соотвествующий setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все я понял, проблема в том что модель сначала посылает сигнал currentRowChanged() когда модель еще не обработала изменения выделения, а только потом selectionChanged().